# Using android vpn on pc through emulator

Tags: windows-10, vpn, android

is it possible to use a vpn for windows browsing via installing an android vpn in emulators such as nox or bluestacks or it just works within the software?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Android emulator on Windows , it will encrypt your connection in programs outside the emulator. It will work as a third party program. [Here](https://androidemulatorforwindows.com/how-to-install-android-vpn-for-pc-using-android-emulator/) is the article that I found with a little bit of browsing.